# ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas - "pip install pandas"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pip

I just installed Python on my office machine. I had installed Python Python 3.7 - 64 bit and Python 3.8 - 32 bit both. Then I uninstalled the 32 bit as my Windows is 64 bit.

I want to install pandas using pip. But I got the following error.

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pandas/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas
```

To resolve this error, I performed the following series of steps.

1. In the command prompt. I set the following:

> set http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy.server.com:8080  set
> https_proxy=https://username:password@proxy.server.com:8080

2. I changed the directory to where the scripts folder are kept.

> cd C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts

3. Then I run the following command

> pip install pandas --user

4. It is giving me following error

*`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Failed to parse: https://username:password@proxy.server.com:8080`*

Is this because of my corporate network settings? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you try python -m pip install pandas ?

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: There must be a problem with the config file. As the error says, it could not parse at the following line where the proxy part is.. This is surely not related to your network, rather a syntactic error... 

According to this link, https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6775, the issue is @ string in the config...replace it with %40

So it will look like https://username:password%40proxy.server.com:8080

Comment: @Peter that issue means you should escape any `@` signs inside the username, e.g. `https://ora.aff%40example.com:password@proxy.server.com:8080`. The `@` after the password shouldn't be escaped.

Comment: Thanks @Peter for setting me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair, you are correct.I had a special character in my password which I replaced with urlencode. That fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue.

I had a special character (#) in my password which I replaced with %23 refer [link](https://www.urlencoder.org/)

After doing this change when I ran pip install pandas --user I got the following error.

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)'))': /simple/certifi/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)'))': /simple/certifi/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)'))': /simple/certifi/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)'))': /simple/certifi/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)'))': /simple/certifi/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/certifi/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/certifi/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement certifi (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for certifi
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)'))) - skipping
```

To fix this issue I used the following command -

```
pip --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org install pandas --user
```

Result -

```
Successfully installed numpy-1.19.0 pandas-1.0.5 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2020.1 six-1.15.0
```